# Groovy subclass called superclass method that accesses closure

Tags: groovy, closures

I have a groovy superclass that looks like:

```
class AGroovyClass {
   private String str = "hello"
   void printString(int nTimes) {
     nTimes.times { println str } 
  }        
}
```

and subclass

```
class AGroovySubclass extends AGroovyClass {
   // some other subclass methods
}
```

My client code calls:

```
new AGroovySubclass().printString(5)
```

And this actually breaks because it says that that there is no such property "str" for AGroovySubclass

I would have thought since the printString method is in AGroovyClass, it should have no problem accessing the "str" property, but clearly I am incorrect. If I wanted to keep "str" private, what is the appropriate way to make this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is an old bug with private access modifier. It works if you define str protected.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-2433

edit: Can you avoid closure, use a for loop instead? Not so cool, but works :)

Comment: dvcs is right, and about the workaround too.  Changing `nTimes.times { println str }` to `for( i in 1..nTimes ) { println str }` -- ie: using a `for` loop rather than the `times` closure -- works

Comment: for loop will perform slightly better (maybe 10 ms) too :)

Comment: Ah yes, thanks. I can use a for loop if needed. I can also just create a local variable outside the closure that points to the member variable and then it works too.

Comment: Belated thanks.  I had just stumbled across this problem, and was just about to post a question.  You saved me the trouble!